# Why doesn't JPanel (panel) get drawn on the green background (the jpanel)?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

Why doesn't JPanel (panel) get drawn on the green background (the jpanel)? I want to be able to do this without extending j panel to...

Furthermore, for java games should i use keybindings or keylistener in java.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Game {

JFrame window;
JPanel panel;

int charPosX = 0;
int charPosY = 0;

public Boolean createGui() { 

    window = new JFrame("Game");
    window.setSize(1000,500);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setVisible(true);
    panel.setLayout(null);;
    panel.setBackground(new Color(65,130,92));

    window.add(panel); 

    return true; //returns true if ran and will be ran by check status in Main.
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    panel.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawRect(100,10,30,40);
    g.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 10);
}



}
```

Comment: Ask yourself this question, who is actually calling your `paintComponent` method?  Maybe add `@Override` to your `paintComponent` and see what that does

Comment: Shell, we also discuss that fact that your `panel` has no definable size nor is it able to manage any child components which you might add to it.  As general recommendation, I'd avoid using components in this way, and implement the functionality through custom painting approaches, as it's more efficient and less error prone

Comment: what do you mean by custom painting approaches? ????

Comment: Rathen the trying to use components as some kind of entity, which, based on you code, you seem to be trying, have a custom component which is responsible for painting the entities itself directly, rather than relying on other components

Comment: Also, take `window.setVisible(true);`  and move it just above `return true;`

Comment: *"Furthermore, for java games should i use keybindings or keylistener in java."* - Key bindings, apart from generating more re-usable code, they solve focus related issues that `KeyListener` suffers from

Comment: Where is your paintComponent method being called from and where is g coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your code for a second and add `@Override` to your `paintComponent` method...

```
public class Game {

    //...

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        panel.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(100, 10, 30, 40);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 20, 10);
    }

}
```

And now we have a compiler error!  This is because `Game` extends `Object` and does not have a `paintComponent` method.  This means that there is no way that the method could be called by any part of the existing painting system, so, it never gets called.

Components make poor "game" entities, they have a lot of "plumbing" which doesn't make them very efficient for this kind of work, you're generally better off heading down a complete custom painting route

[image: Example]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Game().createGui();
            }
        });
    }

    JFrame window;
    GamePanel panel;

    int charPosX = 0;
    int charPosY = 0;

    public Boolean createGui() {

        window = new JFrame("Game");
        window.setSize(1000, 500);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new GamePanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(65, 130, 92));
        window.add(panel);

        window.setVisible(true);
        return true; //returns true if ran and will be ran by check status in Main.
    }

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle entity = new Rectangle(100, 10, 30, 40);

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.draw(entity);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.fill(entity);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Also note, I called `window.setVisible(true);` only after I had added the `panel` to the `window`, this is because Swing is lazy when it comes to adding/removing components.  If you want to add/remove components after the UI has been realized on the screen, you'll need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container to trigger a layout and paint pass

Also, beware, there is a difference between `paintComponent` and `paintComponents` ;)

I would highly recommend having a look at [Painting in AWT Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to gain a better understanding of how painting works in Swing and how you can take advantage of it

Comment: btw im trying to do this so i can play a game at school or something idk.

Comment: wait what is GamePanel From. ???? Also how come even though you created the Jpanel (gamepanel idk what it is) but already extended JPanel

Comment: `public class GamePanel extends JPanel {` ... it's included in the example if you scroll down a bit. It's a custom class, which extends `JPanel`, it overrides the `paintComponent` method (from `JPanel`) and because of the way the painting sub-system works, will now be called when the component needs to be painted - read through the linked tutorials mentioned at the bottom of the answer